# Redis time jumps forward and goes backwards

Tags: redis

This script shows that the timestamp that redis returns seems to jump forward a lot and then go backwards from time to time. This happens regularly throughout the run, on every run. What's going on? Is this documented anywhere? I stumbled on this as it messes up my sliding window rate limiter.

```
res_0, res_1 = 0, 0
for _ in range(200):
    script = f"""
        local time = redis.call("TIME")
        local current_time = time[1] .. "." .. time[2]
        return current_time
    """
    res_0 = res_1
    res_1 = float(await redis.eval(script, numkeys=0))
    print(res_1 - res_0)
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

```
1667745169.747809
0.011765003204345703
0.01197195053100586
0.011564016342163086
0.011634111404418945
0.012428998947143555
0.011847972869873047
0.011600971221923828
0.011788129806518555
0.012033939361572266
0.012130022048950195
0.01160883903503418
0.011954069137573242
0.012022972106933594
0.011958122253417969
0.011713981628417969
0.011844873428344727
0.012138128280639648
0.011618852615356445
0.011570215225219727
0.011890888214111328
0.011478900909423828
0.7928261756896973
-0.5926899909973145
0.11812996864318848
0.11584997177124023
0.12353992462158203
0.1199800968170166
0.11719989776611328
0.12331008911132812
-0.8117339611053467
0.011723995208740234
0.01131582260131836
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this behavior is **floating point arithmetic** on the calling code side: parsing floats would inevitably round (not sure about the extent, since you didn't tell what platform you are coding against) the input value and the original result precision is lost. So, I would suggest to review your logic so that you process the two components of the result returned by `TIME` independently using a couple of integers / longs instead.

In addition to that, apart from the obvious possibility of an issue with the clock of the Redis server, there may also be the chance you are contacting different Redis hosts along with each iteration - this may hold true in the event you are using a multi-node Redis topology (replication or cluster).